# СчитаННые или считаНые?

Tags: орфография

[Русский орфографический словарь и другие словари](http://lopatin.academic.ru/142124/%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9): **считаНый - с одной Н.**

[Русско-английский словарь и другие словари](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/eng_rus/317320/%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5): **считаННый - с двумя Н.**

Причём в обоих случаях значение - "очень малое количество", и примеры приводятся одни и те же: считан(н)ые минуты, часы и т. д.

Я так понимаю: если корень  -СЧИТ-, то писать надо одну Н по правилу написания отглагольных прилагательных (считаные минуты).

А если корень -чит- (считанный с листа текст), то тогда НН (у причастия есть приставка и зависимое слово).

***Почему такой разброд в словарях? Что с этим делать?***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Вопрос № 257376*

В орфографическом словаре в качестве прилагательного дано слово "считаный" с одной буквой "н", а в Толковом словаре есть только причастие "считанный" в том же значении (совсем немного). Как правильно?

*Ответ справочной службы русского языка*

**Слово считаные в значении 'очень немногие' пишется с одним Н. Написание этого слова приведено в соответствие общему правилу: в отглагольных прилагательных, образованных от бесприставочных глаголов несовершенного вида, пишется одно Н. Раньше написание считанный приводилось в списке исключений, этим и вызвана фиксация с двумя Н в Большом толковом словаре.**

---

Я бы так и оставил в "списке исключений". Потому что действие здесь очень чувствуется, это "не совсем прилагательное", считан(н)ые минуты - это не жареная рыба.

Comment: Нашла и я информацию. С одной Н надо писать считаНые минуты. "Под новое правило естественно подпадают образования деланый (деланое равнодушие), считаный (считаные минуты) и доморощеный, до сих пор писавшиеся с нн, а также конченный (конченный человек), писавшееся с одним н. )" http://pravopisanie.academic.ru/16/%C2%A7_058-069._%D0%94%D0%92%D0%9E%D0%99%D0%9D%D0%AB%D0%95_%D0%A1%D0%9E%D0%93%D0%9B%D0%90%D0%A1%D0%9D%D0%AB%D0%95

Answer (score 3):

Я вообще считаю, что правила менять не следует. Вот как мы запомнили "считанные" в списке исключений -"отглагольных прилагательных, образованных от глаголов несовершенного вида в значении совершенного", пусть бы так и было, но в 1999 г. Лопатин разделил написание прилагательного со значением "немногочисленный" и причастие (= те, которые были считаны) от глагола совершенного вида считать, который употребляется как информационный термин в знач. "получить, снять информацию" - считанные данные). Лопатин представляет Институт русского языка им. В. В. Виноградова Российской академии наук, т. е. самую авторитетную и самую официальную организацию в области изучения русского языка, в том числе и его орфографии и пунктуации. Поэтому к нему прислушиваются, его мнение считается официальным, и мы теперь, видимо, должны писать в соответствии с его словарём. Он был переиздан в 2005 г., там тоже -нн-.

Так что это не разброд, а следствие последней реформы.

Answer (score 1):

В Нацкорусе  "считанные" минуты/часы и т.д  употребляются 1000 раз, а "считаные" - только 40 раз.

Считанные минуты - это не короткие минуты, а вполне обычные, просто их мало. Значение небольшого количества имеет **все сочетание**, а не одно слово.

Поэтому не стоило бы ради простоты письма все "приводить к общему правилу".  Хотя в данном случае мы имеем переносное значение причастия в устойчивом выражении, но желательно, чтобы оно сохраняло форму признака по действию, то есть две буквы НН.